# When I imported my model from FBX, some part of models and armatures are missing

Tags: export, import, .fbx

[image]

When I imported my model from FBX, some part of models and armatures were missing. I did double-checked everything in Outliner, and they look fine.

I tried to find anything wrong with exporting or importing, but I'm loss for words.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Hi, Duarte. Im not sure I understand my error, so I fixed some.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I see you are talking about exporting AND importing? Are you simply testing if and how your model ends up into FBX-format? Or something else?

Comment: Question is really vague - but something to check based on images  - You have checked the option "only deform bones" - this means that if you have disabled deform option in bone of your armature, it won't get exported.

Comment: Hi, Ezez, Im talking about exporting & importing the FBX file. 

I've also checked every deformed opinion in the bone of the armature and checked the "Only Deform Bones" opinion in Export FBX before exporting it to FBX, however, the result is still same. My apology that my post is ambiguous, that was because I was trying to fix this all day and night.

Think Im going to be insane.

Comment: Just came back to inform I've found solution, thanks to Better fbx importer, after surfing the google search.  

https://blendermarket.com/products/better-fbx-importer--exporter